python error with faiss on GPU with cuda despite successful installation
I'm working on a Google Cloud VM with CUDA 12. I tried to install either faiss-gpu-cu12 or faiss-gpu-cu12[fix_cuda] using either a venv or pyenv virtual environment, under python 3.12.4. For the application we also need langchain packages as below:
python --version
Python 3.12.4

python -m pip install langchain langchain-huggingface langchain-community faiss-gpu-cu12[fix_cuda]

pip gives no error and everything looks fine, but when I run the minimal example below:
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

docs = [ 'sefsl;fk lskdf;lk s', 'ewrl kwelklekfl ls ;' ]
embedder = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

f = FAISS.from_texts(docs, embedding=embedder)
embeddings = embedder.encode(docs)

I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/faiss.py", line 55, in dependable_faiss_import
    import faiss
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/faiss/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .loader import *
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/faiss/loader.py", line 111, in <module>
    from .swigfaiss import *
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/faiss/swigfaiss.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _swigfaiss
ImportError: /home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/faiss/_swigfaiss.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/minimal-faiss-expl2.py", line 9, in <module>
    f = FAISS.from_texts(docs, embedding=embedder)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/faiss.py", line 1042, in from_texts
    return cls.__from(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/faiss.py", line 994, in __from
    faiss = dependable_faiss_import()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jupyterlab_user/erwan/RAG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/faiss.py", line 57, in dependable_faiss_import
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not import faiss python package. Please install it with `pip install faiss-gpu` (for CUDA supported GPU) or `pip install faiss-cpu` (depending on Python version).

It looks like the Faiss library is not installed properly, even though pip gave no error when installing package faiss-gpu-cu12. Is there anything I missed? For instance, is there any known incompatibility between the packages above?
For now I'm restricted to use faiss-cpu, so any suggestion welcome!

Additional info:
$ pip freeze | grep faiss
faiss-gpu-cu12==1.8.0.2

$ pip freeze | grep langchain
langchain==0.3.3
langchain-community==0.3.2
langchain-core==0.3.12
langchain-huggingface==0.1.0
langchain-text-splitters==0.3.0

$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0


you probably would have seen this, https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/b77061ff5eb2d5dc3b1fc25b240578c2d686a646/INSTALL.md?plain=1#L8 seems to indicate it only supports CUDA 11.4 and 12.1? I would suggest adding your CUDA version into the question. I don't use any of these libraries so feel free to disregard this

Can you mention the versions of the libraries that you are using? i.e. langchain, langchain-huggingface, langchain-community, faiss-gpu

@python_user omg I think you found the issue: it can only be installed with conda... Feel free to write an answer telling me to RTFM!

Just a note, as per your recent edit, you seem to be using Cuda 11.0 not 12.0. But you are specifying faiss-gpu-cu12 which is for cuda 12.x versions. Although they recommend to install using conda channels, I was able to install faiss-gpu-cu12 via pip on my linux machine.

@Erwan I have done so, I will remove the answer if its no longer true

To reproduce your environment, please write the information about VM spec, OS and etc

As per the installation readme for faiss, it currently seems to only support CUDA versions 11.4 and 12.1. Your post indicates you are on CUDA 11.0.


faiss-gpu, containing both CPU and GPU indices, is available on Linux (x86_64 only) for CUDA 11.4 and 12.1


Further, the readme for faiss-gpu-cu12 mentions

The faiss-gpu-cu12 package (the binaries contained in it) is minor version compatible with CUDA and will work dynamically linked with CUDA 12.X (X>=1).

So it seems you have to be on version 12.1 or above if using version 12.
PS: I added this as an answer in response to this.

Thank you, at least this explains my issue. I tried with conda but it didn't work, probably due to the cuda version, indeed. I will check with colleagues on Monday if this can be fixed.

I tried with the right cuda version, in every possible variant of the environment, and even with the help of two colleagues, we were unable to make it work, unfortunately... I give up, but your answer was still the best I received!

@Erwan thanks for being considerate, appreciate it

First check this since your running python12:
pyenv install 3.10.11  # Example Python version
pyenv virtualenv 3.10.11 faiss-env
pyenv activate faiss-env

And did you try this and is cuda necessary?
For CUDA 12:
pip uninstall faiss-gpu-cu12
pip install faiss-gpu-cu12[fix_cuda] 

